# How to add a filter to a google analytics view?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Ok, so I am trying to programmatically add filters to a google analytics view. The guide google puts out:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/filters/insert#examples

The guide shows you how to insert a filter. But this filter is created at the account level and then you need to add it to a specific view. How can I add it to a view?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtFilterGuide#link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a [profile filter link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profileFilterLinks/insert):

```
# Note: This code assumes you have an authorized Analytics service object.
# See the Filters Developer Guide for details.

# This request creates a new profile filter link.
try:
  analytics.management().profileFilterLinks().insert(
      accountId='123456',
      webPropertyId='UA-123456-1',
      profileId='7654321',
      body={
          'filterRef': {
              'id': '1223334444'
          }
      }
  ).execute()

except TypeError, error:
  # Handle errors in constructing a query.
  print 'There was an error in constructing your query : %s' % error

except HttpError, error:
  # Handle API errors.
  print ('There was an API error : %s : %s' %
         (error.resp.status, error.resp.reason))
```